# Kafka broker JVM settings below 1GB

Tags: java, apache-kafka, heap-memory

I am running a standalone kafka broker on an EC2 4GB RAM instance. In the default settings, Kafka is configured to use 1GB memory
 -Xmx1G -Xms1G

Since the VM has only 4GB memory, is it possible to configure the JVM settings to use 512MB? How should I do that? Will Kafka run properly with 512MB memory or is 1GB the minimum required?

Comment: 6-8GB is actually the production grade best performance. Not sure why you'd want less than 4 given that all consumer requests of the latest offsets are directly off the heap. You should be able to safely use 3GB if no other process is on those machines

Comment: I understand. But its a test server and also has mongodb and some node services running, so want to limit the memory consumption by kafka which is consistently using about 900-1000MB

Comment: Alright, well being a Java server process, I'm fairly sure most of that memory is required. Are you also running Zookeeper on the same machine?

Comment: Yes. Kafka, zookeeper, mongodb, redis, nodejs (4-5 apps). Its a 4GB EC2 Ubuntu VM. Will be moving to an 8GB one for production and separating the mongodb from the VMs. Want to limit the memory usage for the development environment

Comment: Hmm. I wouldn't really consider that production. Loose one server, you lose more than half your app stack

Comment: For more information, you might want to reference https://www.confluent.io/resources/apache-kafka-confluent-enterprise-reference-architecture/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set your own JVM heap settings, you just have to export `KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS` and Kafka will pick it up when starting.

For example, to set the heap to 512MB, run

```
export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx512m -Xms512M"
```