# Bash Conditional based on EC2 RAM Amount?

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

I am running Kafka on a AWS T2.micro (1 GB RAM) EC2 instance.

This is causing issues because Kafka is by default configured to use 1 GB ram according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572335/kafka-broker-jvm-settings-below-1gb).

I am installing Kafka via a bash script that automates some things including downloading some connectors.

**How would I check the amount of RAM my EC2 instance has via Bash and then, if RAM < 6 GB, run the command "export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx256M -Xms128M**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add this to your bash script:

```
if [ $(free -g  | grep Mem | awk '{print $2}') -lt 6 ]; then
   export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx256M -Xms128M"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering how to feed the memory info to the script. Grep seems really powerful.